# CMAKE CGAL QT5 error while building APP - UBUNTU

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, qt5, cgal

Everytime time I try to ->

cd /home/alexandre/XCeng/build_xc/xc_utils
cmake ../xc_utils/src

according to the developer instructions (https://github.com/xcfem/xc/blob/master/install/install.linux.md)

I got this error:

I reinstalled Qt5, CGAL and many other dependencies, but I still got this error. Any ideas on what to do next?

```
CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/CGAL/CGALConfig.cmake:137 (message):
  ERROR: The CGAL_Qt5 library was not configured.  CGAL was configured with
  WITH_CGAL_Qt5=ON, **but one of the dependencies of CGAL_Qt5 was not
  configured properly.**
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/CGAL/CGALConfig.cmake:147 (check_cgal_component)
  ../CMake/find_packages.cmake:7 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:37 (INCLUDE)
```